# Unable to install sequelize NPM node_modules/.sequelize.DELETE/node_modules/debug

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to NodeJS and would like to use Sequelize.
I installed PostgreSQL and Node on a new CentOS7 VM.

```
node -v v10.14.1
npm -v v6.5.0
```

And when I try to install `sequelize`

```
[vmuser@accounts-1 accounts-nodejs]$ npm install --save sequelize
npm ERR! path /mnt/hgfs/vms_shared/dev/accounts-nodejs/node_modules/.sequelize.DELETE/node_modules/debug
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/mnt/hgfs/vms_shared/dev/accounts-nodejs/node_modules/.sequelize.DELETE/node_modules/debug' -> '/mnt/hgfs/vms_shared/dev/accounts-nodejs/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/debug'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vmuser/.npm/_logs/2018-12-12T15_42_17_715Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you do not have a package.json file.The `--save` flag instructs npm to save it as a dependency in package.json.
So, first run `npm init` it is an interactive command line process. Then install sequelize

Answer (score 0):

Tanks for your answer

In fact, I was working on a VM and the project folder is an hosted one.
If I work in a local folder of the VM everything is fine.

Strange behaviour but it resolved my issue.